# How to convert a cardano address into a public key hash?

Tags: plutus, transaction, testnet, public-key

After spending some time learning Plutus with emulators, I decided to start learning how to actually deploy and use the scripts in the testnet. In this process, I installed cardano-cli and created multiple key files, such as "payment.addr", "payment.skey", "payment.vkey", etc. But now, the validator script that I created requires as one of it's parameters a Plutus `AssocMap` associating public key hashes to integers.

My question is, based on the keys I created, how can I find out their `PubKeyHash`? I believe this is related to "payment.addr", but I'm not sure.

Comment: How to get this value when using e.g. Nami Wallet?

Comment: Is there a way to get key-hash from payment.address only?

Comment: @AdamMachera See my new answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

- `cardano-cli address key-hash --payment-verification-key STRING`
- `cardano-cli address key-hash --payment-verification-key-file FILE`

You should use your `payment.vkey`

Comment: This is the `cborHex` value in the `.vkey` file yes?

Answer (score 6):

If anyone is trying to do this using cardano-serialization-lib and Nami:

```
const PUBKEY_HASH = async () => {
  const cardano = window.cardano;

  const pkh = Loader.Cardano.BaseAddress.from_address(
    Loader.Cardano.Address.from_bytes(
      Buffer.from(await cardano.getChangeAddress(), "hex")
    )
  )
    .payment_cred()
    .to_keyhash();

  return pkh;
};
```

Assuming you are using a loader like the one from [spacebudz](https://github.com/Berry-Pool/spacebudz/blob/main/src/cardano/market/loader.js) and you are importing Buffer `import { Buffer } from "buffer";`

**UPDATE**

Made a more abstract version that takes a string (the bech32 address) and returns another string (the public key hash)

```
function addrToPubKeyHash(bech32Addr) {
  const pkh = Loader.Cardano.BaseAddress.from_address(
    Loader.Cardano.Address.from_bech32(bech32Addr)
  )
    .payment_cred()
    .to_keyhash();

  return toHex(pkh.to_bytes());
}
```

Comment: Sorry `fromHex` is defined as `const fromHex = (hex) => Buffer.from(hex, "hex")`

Comment: And `toHex` `const toHex = (bytes) => Buffer.from(bytes).toString("hex")`

Answer (score 2):

I am working on this as well... I am not sure but this seems quite promising

https://input-output-hk.github.io/cardano-addresses/demo/

Maybe this is usefull as well

https://cips.cardano.org/cips/cip19/#shelleyaddresses

Comment: If you are using the serialization lib, my answer may help

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "cardano-address address inspect" syntax to get the public key hash from an address without requiring the verification key. Requiring the verification key assumes having access to the file while addresses can be shared without having to know the owner.
This link can help: https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-addresses

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just pass the address to Plutus and then convert it there to a public key hash using the function in `Ledger.Address`:

```
{-# INLINABLE toPubKeyHash #-}
-- | The PubKeyHash of the address, if any
toPubKeyHash :: Address -> Maybe PubKeyHash
```

The address is serializable so you can pass it easily and get a proper instance of `Address` that you can use at your will in your Plutus code.

Comment: Are you sure this `Address` is a bech32 string? I don't think it is https://staging.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/plutus-ledger-api/html/Plutus-V1-Ledger-Address.html#t:Address

Comment: I don't know if this deserialisation is this easy, actually. I haven't tried yet. But, there must be a function in Plutus to deserialise the string to the Address class.

Comment: This is getting strange. Why is it so difficult to find a function in Plutus that parses the address representation to the address class ?