# Getting Validator Hash

Tags: plutus, smart-contract, testnet, address

I'm checking the `Value` locked by certain `ValidatorHash` of another script that I deployed. Does anyone know how to get `Ledger.Address` or `ValidatorHash` from Plutus or cardano-cli? I know the "address" that is a string that starts with "addr_test1..." but how do I turn that into the above Plutus types?

Sort of like [this](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/4274/how-to-convert-a-cardano-address-into-a-public-key-hash) question but for `ValidatorHash`. I know that you can use `cardano-cli transaction policyid` for monetary policies, is there an equivalent for `ValidatorHash`?

Thanks!

Comment: So you want to go from `address` (addr_test1...) to `Ledger.Address` or `ValidatorHash`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested on testnet, `cardano-cli transaction policyid --script-file ...` works.

Just make sure in your Haskell code to include something like the following to turn it into an address:

```
testnetDumpValidatorHash :: ValidatorHash
testnetDumpValidatorHash = "10101010110101010101010101010101010101010101010101123456"
 
testnetDumpAddress :: Ledger.Address
testnetDumpAddress = scriptHashAddress testnetDumpValidatorHash
```